# For loop and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, append

I'm making my first web project in JavaScript. I don't know how to use for loop properly. I'm trying to get this result:

```
text
text
text
text
```

But I get this:

```
text
```

And that's the code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; 1++) {
$("#sth").append("text" + "<br>");
}
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6K7Ja/

I just started learning JavaScript. Help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't even get the single line "text" because of the syntax error. This is a "typo question" and should probably be closed.

Comment: and never append something continuously repetitive to the DOM. try var html +=  "text" + "<br>"; and at the end do an append.

Comment: You have a typo, replace `1++` with `i++`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code has `1++` where it should be `i++`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    text += "text<br>";
}
$("#sth").append(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the append out of the loop. Add the values to a variable then append that variable once. What happens when you do it how you are now, is jQuery will do that append method each time it goes through that loop. That's bad because it will keep doing it *every time* and slowing you down. It's better to go through the loop and save what you want to append to a variable. Then just append that variable *once*. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var appendText = []; //We can define an array here if you need to play with the results in order or just use a string otherwise.
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    appendText.push("text" + "<br>"); //This adds each thing we want to append to the array in order.
}

//Out here we call the append once
//Since we defined our variable as an array up there we join it here into a string
appendText.join(" ");
$("#sth").append(appendText);
```

You can see this working in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNy8e/) and play around with it.

Here's some reading materials you should check out:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Comment: This helped me a lot :)